# How to undo rm -rf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, linux-kernel, linuxmint

How we can undo rm -rf command ?
For example, I have Application folder. And I have remove it by

```
rm -rf Application
```

But it was my mistake and want to recovery or want that Application Folder. But its not in Trash folder. What should I do now ? Is there any command undo rm -rf

Comment: No, this is why people new to linux should not use -rf, but -ri.

Comment: Could try something like [this](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/)... no guarantees though. Keep good backups.

Comment: Build a time machine, or restore from your backup.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. Crossposting would not have been required, since this has already been asked on SU.

Answer (score 12):

With your backup tapes.
Unix does not protect you from doing bad things. You specified the `r`ecursive & `f`orce flags, it assumed you knew what that would mean, and did what you asked.

If the data is important ***power the machine off immediately*** (seriously, rip the plug out of the wall before the operating system writes something in that "free" space and destroys your data) and contact a data retrieval company.
(The fact that you're asking this question indicates to me that you lack the experience required to attempt recovery yourself - I'm not going to send you down that particular rabbit hole.)

If the data is not important, try a utility like [`unrm`](http://freecode.com/projects/unrm).